# Temporarily disabling javascript alerts from a certain page?

Tags: javascript, cpanel, alert

I'm making code edits to my website within cPanel's file manager. With the latest update of cPanel v.104, after saving my file, control+Z does not revert my changes.

Now, A javascript alert pops up asking: "Are you sure you want to save? The file will be overwritten."

I hypothesize that a redefinition of the alert function, locally via my javascript console could stop this behavior and thus reclaim my control+Z ability.

```
window.alert = function() {};
```

Well, this does successfully disable alerts when I throw it in the console. Is it incorrect methodology to paste this in the console? Is there something else I should do?

Here is a thread tracking this issue:
https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/cpanel-40934-website-com-says-are-you-sure-you-want-to-save-the-file-will-be-overwritten.701853/

Comment: I think there is much more going behind the scenes than just an alert, Only the official support can patch it.

Comment: @Khalil I agree, just trying to hack around and see if this will fix the issue. In any case I should probably be doing my webdev locally anyways

Comment: "Correct methodology" implies you have codebase. If you are trying to to make this page work better for you in your browser, anything goes. Maybe there is a browser extension that can do something like this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Alert box is used to provide the user some information. When trying to receive approval or disapproval, `confirm()` is used.

Try pasting this code in your web dev tools console.

```
window.confirm = function() {};
```